# Requests.get returns 403 while everything works fine in browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, http-status-code-403

when i request https://haveibeenpwned.com/unifiedsearch/jonathan@gmail.com from browser, everything works but when i request it from Python,it throws a 403.

I set up the user agent in the python request but i keep getting 403 response.

My code:

```
import requests 

url="https://haveibeenpwned.com/unifiedsearch/jonathan@gmail.com"

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36'}

r=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)  # 403
```

Does anyone have any ideas why it's throwing a 403 ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: They have the cloudflare anti-bot system enabled, you may want to try out the official API: https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2

Answer (score 1):

Try printing out `r.text` it has the body of the response.  I got a 403 trying your code.   the text indicates its trying a captia for you to prove your not a bot (which of course this is .... )